# Выбор роута в Kohana 3 для Pagination

Tags: paging, kohana

```
Route::set('modules', 'module/<controller>(/page/<pnum>)(/<action>(/<data>))', array(
    'pnum'=>'[0-9]+'
    ))->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'pnum'       => 1,
        'data'       => '',
    ));
```

Имеется вот такой роут для подгрузки модулей в основной контроллер, в модуле выводятся новости по ссылке `http://example/posts/index`
но в пагинаторе ссылки генерируются по такой схеме `http://example/module/posts/index`

Вопрос - как мне выбрать стандартный роут для модуля??? Модуль подключается через `Request::factory('module/posts')->execute();`

```
Route::set('default', '(<page>(/page/<pnum>)(/<actname>(/<data>)))', array('pnum'=>'[0-9]+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'pages',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'page'       => 'homepage',
        'actname'    => 'index',
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Модуль pagination под Kohana 3.2 написан и довольно неплохо работает. Только, мой вам совет, не пользуйте пагинацию в роуте!!! Передавайте данные о странице через $_GET, поверьте опыту!

[вот](http://wadya.pp.ua/2012/01/02/pagination-in-kohana-3-2/) вполне неплохо описано

Comment: Оттуда и брал пример